# Get all strongly-typed document of a certain type with Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a web service in which I want to retrieve all document of a certain content type but as strongly typed object. I tried to use this:

```
var contentType = Services.ContentTypeService.GetContentType(PensionPoint.ModelTypeAlias);
var points = Services.ContentService.GetContentOfContentType(contentType.Id).ToList();
```

However, I get IContent object on which I can't do Object.Property. How can I retrieve the same items but as strongly-types object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong Umbraco API, you need to use the Umbraco Helper to retrieve a published content item rather than the Service API that returns an `IContent` item.

```
var umbracoHelper = 
      new Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);
var pensionPoints = 
      umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtRoot().First().Descendants<PensionPoint>();
```

Of course, you might be able to get an `UmbracoHelper` instance directly if your code is within a controller or view.

Also, please be aware that the code above assumes your content is under a single "home" node.

Finally, performance may not be very good if your site has a lot of content, in which case you may want to use an XPATH query and cast the result to your class.